# How to change the RPM default python module configurations to python3 on CentOS 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, centos7

I've installed multiple python versions on CentOS 7 and setup the alternatives like below:

```
# alternatives --list|grep -i python
python  manual  /usr/local/python3/bin/python3.6
```

But the RPM command still shows the default python module configurations like:

```
# rpm -q --provides python
Distutils
python = 2.7.5-90.el7
python(abi) = 2.7
python(abi) = 2.7
python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-90.el7
python-abi = 2.7
python-argparse = 2.7.5-90.el7
python-ctypes = 1.0.1
python-hashlib = 20081120
python-sqlite = 2.3.2
python-uuid = 1.31
python2 = 2.7.5
```

the expected output is:

```
# rpm -q --provides python
Distutils
python = **3.6**
python(abi) = **3.6**
........
```

Is here anyway i can modify the RPM default python version to new installed 3.6?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/usr/local/python3` indicates that you have compiled. You shouldn't really do that. The good approach is installing `python3` package.

Comment: is here any possibility that i could manually configure the "rpm provider parameters" to use new added python version by default?  thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your end goal? Suppose you got RPM to work the way you want, then what? I ask because it seems like you are trying to use RPM in a way it is not designed to work.

Comment: I expect the outputs of RPM python selection could be:  # rpm -q --provides python
Distutils
python = 3.6
python(abi) = 3.6
python(abi) = 3.6